# How to create a paypal order with default values for billing and shipping

Tags: php, rest, paypal, payment, autofill

I need to prepopulate my paypal payment form with the billing address and shipping address. I am able to complete the shipping details but not the billing.

```
paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
                reference_id: "PUHF",
                description: "Sporting Goods",
                custom_id: "CUST-HighFashions",
                soft_descriptor: "HighFashions",
                amount: {
                    currency_code: "USD",
                    value: "220.00",
                    breakdown: {
                        item_total: {
                            currency_code: "USD",
                            value: "180.00"
                        },
                        discount: {
                            currency_code: "USD",
                            value: "10.00"
                        },
                        shipping: {
                            currency_code: "USD",
                            value: "30.00"
                        },
                        handling: {
                            currency_code: "USD",
                            value: "10.00"
                        },
                        tax_total: {
                            currency_code: "USD",
                            value: "20.00"
                        },
                        shipping_discount: {
                            currency_code: "USD",
                            value: "10.00"
                        }
                    }
                },
                items: [{
                    name: "T-Shirt",
                    description: "Green XL",
                    sku: "sku01",
                    unit_amount: {
                         currency_code: "USD",
                         value: "90.00"
                    },
                    tax: {
                        currency_code: "USD",
                        value: "10.00"
                    },
                    quantity: "1",
                    category: "PHYSICAL_GOODS"
                },
                    {
                    name: "Shoes",
                    description: "Running, Size 10.5",
                    sku: "sku02",
                    unit_amount: {
                         currency_code: "USD",
                         value: "45.00"
                    },
                    tax: {
                        currency_code: "USD",
                        value: "5.00"
                    },
                    quantity: "2",
                    category: "PHYSICAL_GOODS"
                }
                ],
                shipping: {
                    method: "United States Postal Service",
            name: {
            full_name: "John Doe"
                    },
                    address: {
                        address_line_1: "123 Townsend St",
                        address_line_2: "Floor 6",
                        admin_area_2: "San Francisco",
                        admin_area_1: "CA",
                        postal_code: "94107",
                        country_code: "US"
                    }
                }
            }]
        })
    },
    // Call your server to finalize the transaction
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        return fetch('/demo/checkout/api/paypal/order/' + data.orderID + '/capture/', {
            method: 'post'
        }).then(function(res) {
            return res.json();
        }).then(function(orderData) {
            // Three cases to handle:
            //   (1) Recoverable INSTRUMENT_DECLINED -> call actions.restart()
            //   (2) Other non-recoverable errors -> Show a failure message
            //   (3) Successful transaction -> Show confirmation or thank you

            // This example reads a v2/checkout/orders capture response, propagated from the server
            // You could use a different API or structure for your 'orderData'
            var errorDetail = Array.isArray(orderData.details) && orderData.details[0];

            if (errorDetail && errorDetail.issue === 'INSTRUMENT_DECLINED') {
                return actions.restart(); // Recoverable state, per:
                // https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/funding-failure/
            }

            if (errorDetail) {
                var msg = 'Sorry, your transaction could not be processed.';
                if (errorDetail.description) msg += '\n\n' + errorDetail.description;
                if (orderData.debug_id) msg += ' (' + orderData.debug_id + ')';
                return alert(msg); // Show a failure message (try to avoid alerts in production environments)
            }

            // Successful capture! For demo purposes:
            console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
            var transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
            alert('Transaction '+ transaction.status + ': ' + transaction.id + '\n\nSee console for all available details');

            // Replace the above to show a success message within this page, e.g.
            // const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
            // element.innerHTML = '';
            // element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
            // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');
        });
    }
}).render('#paypal-button-container')
```

I need to populate the billing details. Everything I tried fails and I found the paypal documentation very unclear.

Can anyone provide a bit of help?

I have tried the code below and it does not work

```
payer: {
                  email_address: 'customer@domain.com',
                  phone: {
                    phone_number: {
                        national_number: '4543433243',
                    }
                  },
                  name: {
                    given_name: 'PayPal',
                    surname: 'Customer',
                  },
                  address: {
                    address_line_1: '123 ABC Street',
                    address_line_2: 'Apt 2',
                    admin_area_2: 'San Jose',
                    admin_area_1: 'CA',
                    postal_code: '95121',
                    country_code: 'US',
                  },
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

`actions.order.create(` and `action.order.capture(` are deprecated and should not be used. See the [standard checkout integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) for information on creating and capturing orders from a backend. The sample code there for node.js , but of course any environment can be used to implement the two routes including PHP.

The `payer` object is also deprecated, so do not use that. Billing information can be sent in the `payment_source.paypal` object, [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-payment_source). It will not be used if the payer uses an existing PayPal account.

Comment: I want to take payment from the frontend. Users need fill in their details in checkout. And then go to payment page where the PayPal widget is. All details need to be prefilled. I do not want my buyers to have to go the PayPal site to make any payment. I need the payment to be done in my site.
I am quite confused with which JavaScript/PHP code is deprecated and which one is not. I find the documentation quite poorly organised but that might be just me.
Is there a class on GitHub that can provide with up to date code?

Comment: The standard integration guide is up to date, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/ .  You'll need two backend routes, one to create an order and one to capture it. Everything else about the approval is done from the frontend JS.